# Packagist api -> search by (a OR b)

Tags: packagist

I read the packagist [api docs](https://packagist.org/apidoc).

You can search by tags:

```
GET https://packagist.org/search.json?tags=[tag]
```

And I found that you can search by multiple tags:

```
https://packagist.org/search.json?tags[]=symfony&tags[]=json
```

Which will list packages that contains both `symfony` **and** `json` tags.

But how can I list packages that contains `symfony` **or** `json` tags ?

Packagist [docs](https://github.com/composer/packagist) says that it uses solr

> The search index uses Solr 3.6, so you will have to install that on
>   your server. If you are running it on a non-standard host or port, you
>   will have to adjust the configuration. See the NelmioSolariumBundle
>   for more details.

But I can't find how to use solr queries in the api tags filter.

---

Edit: tags filter won't do the work - [code](https://github.com/composer/packagist/blob/055c89e4393e950d9c3a00fe8319c80041221c6f/src/Packagist/WebBundle/Controller/WebController.php#L107)